# Why elements of the set can be Goldbach pairs for a given even number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let's take even number $100$ as an example (an example in the [paper](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_14052169840388&key=4ca1c8ebe982149656ef795be05c6fef&libId=f83e02d7-80dc-4259-8c86-43a7386c3da6&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fmymathforum.com%2Fnumber-theory%2F45185-goldbach-s-conjecture-chinese-remainder-theorem.html&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fvixra.org%2Fpdf%2F1407.0057v1.pdf&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fmymathforum.com%2Fnumber-theory%2F&title=Goldbach's%20conjecture%20and%20Chinese%20Remainder%20Theorem%20-%20My%20Math%20Forum&txt=paper)):

Fom $2$ to $\sqrt{100}$ there's four primes:$\ 2,\ 3,\ 5,\ 7.\ $Let
$$
\begin{align*} 
&A=\{n: n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, n<2,n \neq 100 \mod 2\}=\{1\}\\ 
&B=\{n: n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, n<3,n \neq 100 \mod 3\}=\{2\}\\ 
&C=\{n: n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, n<5,n \neq 100 \mod 5\}=\{1,2,3,4\}\\ 
&D=\{n: n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, n<7,n \neq 100 \mod 7\}=\{1,3,4,5,6\}\\ 
&E=\{n: n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, n<100,n \mod 2 \in A,n \mod 3 \in B,n \mod 5 \in C,n \mod 7 \in D\}=\{11, 17, 29, 41, 47, 53, 59, 71, 83, 89\}
\end{align*}
$$
We see that elements of the set $E$: $\ 11+89=100,\ 17+83=100, \ 29+71=100,\ 41+59=100, \,47+53=100$

Why elements of the set $E$ can be Goldbach pairs for the given even number 100?

> Maybe there's an answer in that paper, but it may take pages and in bad math, hope there's an answer of coolness.Any revise,modify,suggestion,edit are welcomed.

Comment: Vixra, not using Latex, and only one reference; any one of these alone is a bad sign.

Comment: ... Apply water to the burned area

Comment: @T.Bongers Thanks, Sage and Pari code for the example see:http://mymathforum.com/number-theory/45185-goldbach-s-conjecture-chinese-remainder-theorem.html

Comment: Microsoft Word, no less. I'm not familiar with vixra; is it supposed to be a version of the arxiv for people ("for the _whole_ community") who have no academic connections and thus can't get an arxiv account?

Comment: The ten elements of $E$ are the numbers that are 5 modulo 6, leaving out 5, 23, 35, 65, 77, and 95 --- which also add up to 100 in pairs (but without benefit of primality).

Comment: Also see: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/176060/why-elements-of-the-set-can-be-goldbach-pairs-for-a-given-even-number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix some large even $n$. The paper constructs the set 
$$A_p = \{0 < m \leq n\,|\, m\not\equiv 0, n\!\pmod{p}\}$$ 
for each prime $p\leq \sqrt{n}$. Now, if $1 < m < n$, then $m$ is certainly prime if $m\in A_p$ for all $p\leq \sqrt{n}$. We want to find such $m, m'$ with $m + m' = n$. Long story short, the paper then uses the Chinese remainder theorem to show that 
$$A = \bigcap_{p\leq \sqrt{n}} A_p$$
is nonempty. (Note that $n$ is even, so $A_2$ is nonempty.) That doesn't follow. There's certainly an element $d$ that satisfies the given system of congruences, but there's no reason why it should be on the interval $[0, n]$. (It's only determined mod $N = \prod_{p\leq \sqrt{n}} p$, which is generally much larger. Much larger, in fact; for $n = 10^4$, the product is more than $10^{36}$.) Without that criterion, it doesn't follow that $d$ is prime.

I think that's what the paper is claiming, anyway. It's very badly written, and it has all the classic hallmarks of bad amateur math: Word instead of LaTeX, being distributed outside of a journal or something like the arxiv, poor writing quality, obsessive detail over trivial examples and completely elementary results (we know about the Chinese Remainder theorem; you don't have to spend two pages discussing it), exactly one reference, and no references to papers or anything beyond introductory textbooks. I really don't want to be that guy (and I hope someone with more patience than me will dissect the paper in more detail), but this is not good math.

Comment: Classic hallmarks of bad amateur math is very interesting: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866526/list-of-classic-hallmarks-of-bad-amateur-math

Comment: I have actually gone down the same path as this "paper", independently of course =) and you're right that there is no guarantee that the number is between 0 and n. However, there are certain symmetries in the set of numbers with the "proper" congruences. For example, if k has the proper congruences, so does N-k. Perhaps these symmetries will allow us to somehow find out how spread out these acceptable congruences are which will help us guarantee it to be in the interval 0 to n.